# combining a groupby MultiIndex headers into one single line header

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
                   hour minute  a1_UNf         a1_UNf     b1_UNf
                   max  max     mean            amax             mean
1min                    
2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   12561.6041666667    12565.5 12560.4821428571
2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   12560.0779220779    12562.5 12559.3311688312
2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   12558.45    12559.5 12557.7
2017-09-19 02:03:00 2   3   12556.2536231884    12560   12555.4347826087
2017-09-19 02:04:00 2   4   12555.9444444444    12557   12555.3518518519
2017-09-19 02:05:00 2   5   12554.859375    12555.5 12554.1875
2017-09-19 02:06:00 2   6   12552.5 12553.5 12551.8
```

I am trying to create new headers which will be a combination of the 2 top headers (were created by a groupby)

Any suggestions to how to make the headers to be
`hour_max    minute_max` etc. ?

I was trying to use:

```
col_name = df.columns.values
```

and it prints:

```
[('hour', 'max') ('minute', 'max') ('a1_UNf', 'mean')
 ('a1_UNf', 'amax') ('b1_UNf', 'mean')]
```

but how can I apply it back as a single header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` with `join`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
#list comprehension alternative
#df.columns = ['{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format(x) for x in df.columns]
print (df)
                     hour_max  minute_max   a1_UNf_mean  a1_UNf_amax  \
1min                                                                   
2017-09-19 02:00:00         2           0  12561.604167      12565.5   
2017-09-19 02:01:00         2           1  12560.077922      12562.5   
2017-09-19 02:02:00         2           2  12558.450000      12559.5   
2017-09-19 02:03:00         2           3  12556.253623      12560.0   
2017-09-19 02:04:00         2           4  12555.944444      12557.0   
2017-09-19 02:05:00         2           5  12554.859375      12555.5   
2017-09-19 02:06:00         2           6  12552.500000      12553.5   

                      b1_UNf_mean  
1min                               
2017-09-19 02:00:00  12560.482143  
2017-09-19 02:01:00  12559.331169  
2017-09-19 02:02:00  12557.700000  
2017-09-19 02:03:00  12555.434783  
2017-09-19 02:04:00  12555.351852  
2017-09-19 02:05:00  12554.187500  
2017-09-19 02:06:00  12551.800000
```

Comment: @Giladbi - Yes, if columns names are strings, `map` working nice.But generally need lsit comprehension, if values are numeric or datetimes.